# $ z \in \Bbb{C}: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(3n-2)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n-1)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z}\right) $ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series convergent ?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(3n-2)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n-1)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z}\right) $$
$$ z \in \Bbb{C} $$

Comment: Well, it is definitely  not convergen when $\mathrm{Re}(z)\leq 0.$ Then the terms do not approach zero.

Comment: Asking to prove convergence implies it converges, but then you link to an example which does not converge. Maybe you mean “decide the convergence of...”

Comment: I don't get this question: can't you simply define it as $\{ z \in \Bbb C: \ \mathrm{the\  series\ is \ convergent} \}$?

Comment: Since this question is lacking context and you have added an answer, it might be better to bring the answer into the question and phrase it as, "is this answer correct?"  This should keep this question from gathering close votes.

Comment: [Self-answered questions are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but this question should also follow the [site guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

I had improved my knowledge a bit and I hope that this is a correct answer.

---

From Dirichlet Series theorem it is known that, if:
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^z} $$
converges for:
$$ \Re(z) = c $$
then it converges for:
$$ z = c + xi $$
$$ x \in \Bbb{R} $$

From this point we only have to check convergence for $\Re(z)$.

---

We known that:

$$ \frac{1}{(3n-2)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n-1)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z} \ge \frac{1}{(3n)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z}$$

$$ \frac{1}{(3n-2)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n-1)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z} \ge \frac{1}{(3n)^z}$$

Hence:

$$ \frac{1}{3^z} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z} = \frac{1}{3^z} \zeta(z) $$
$$ \Re(z) > 1 $$

Finally the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(3n-2)^z} + \frac{1}{(3n-1)^z} - \frac{1}{(3n)^z}\right) $ is divergent for $\Re(z) < 1$. The same method can be made to set some upperbound.

Comment: (+1) The sum is $\left(1-\frac2{3^z}\right)\zeta(z)$.